# StringBuilder in .net not writing entire file

Tags: vb.net, stringbuilder

I'm trying to write a text file. Here's my main,slightly clipped for clarity:

```
Private Sub WriteProperty(FilePath As String)
    Try
        SB = New StringBuilder
        WriteConfig()
        'a bunch of methods similar to WriteConfig here...
        Dim File As New System.IO.StreamWriter(FilePath)
        File.WriteLine(SB.ToString())
    Catch ex As Exception
        Dim X As Integer = 5 'cheesy way to add a breakpoint
    End Try
End Sub
```

And here is one of about a dozen subs that add text to the file:

```
Private Sub WriteConfig()
    Dim TempSB As New StringBuilder
    TempSB.AppendLine("[CONFIG]")
    TempSB.AppendLine("[END_CONFIG]")
    TempSB.AppendLine("")
    SB.Append(TempSB)
End Sub
```

There are about a dozen methods that add things like this, most of them add about 2k of text instead of the couple of lines in this example. When I examine SB in the debugger the total result is a little over 15k long. But when I open the file, it's 12k, and the end is all missing - it cuts off in the middle of one of the strings. There is no exception raised.

I know SB has problems with lots of little appends, which is why I used the TempSB's in the subs, but it has the exact same problem, and if I add them directly to SB instead the only difference is the "break" occurs a few characters earlier.

Can anyone offer a suggestion as to what might be happening?

Comment: StringBuilder is not broken.  Forgetting the Using statement is a standard bug.

Comment: What are the "problems" `StringBuilder` have with lots of little `.Append`s?

Comment: @Fabio - a number of .Net stream-related objects double their memory allocation when you reach the currently allocated size. The table for holding these blocks is small, so if you organize your writes such that they keep hitting this buffer limit, you can "run out of space" even at very small sizes. I've killed Streams at 50k.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

StreamWriter uses an internal buffer. You need to Close() your StreamWriter to force it to write the remaining buffered data to the file. Better yet, wrap it in a Using statement. That will call its Dispose(), which in turn calls its Close().

```
Using File As New System.IO.StreamWriter(FilePath)
    File.WriteLine(SB.ToString())
End Using
```

There's a convenience method that will do this for you in a single line:

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(FilePath, SB.ToString())
```

Comment: Wow, thank you sir! And the single-line is cleaner too.